# Lock screen orientation of a DreamService

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, dreamservice

I've been fiddling with the new [`DreamService` API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/dreams/DreamService.html) for the past few hours, and it's pretty sweet. I do have one question, though.

I'd like to lock the screen orientation to landscape when the `DreamService` is shown. The purpose of the `DreamService` is to show a number of widescreen photos, and I'd rather not have the black bars at the top and bottom of the screen.

I've tried a number of things, including `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)` in Java code, and `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` in the manifest file, but none have worked.

This makes me wonder: Is it possible to lock the orientation of a `DreamService`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android developer team confirmed that this currently isn't possible during a live developer Hangout some time ago.

I believe Google wants `DreamServices` to work in both screen orientations, so that's why it isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

**Workaround:** use this lib https://github.com/rongi/rotate-layout

*build.gradle*

```
 dependencies {
        compile 'rongi.rotate-layout:rotate-layout:2.0.0'
    }
```

*your_daydream_layout.xml*

```
<com.github.rongi.rotate_layout.layout.RotateLayout  
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   app:angle="-90">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/daydream_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#2a2e31" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dream_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="..."
            android:textColor="#abc"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</com.github.rongi.rotate_layout.layout.RotateLayout>
```

---

**And btw:** 
Allow to auto rotate your daydream .. from https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40226

> "It looks like a fix for this has been implemented (and nobody told
>   us).  Unfortunately, it doesn't work properly.  On my Nexus 6p (6.0.1,
>   Build #MHC19Q), if I swipe to the left-most screen (Google Now?), hit
>   the hamburger menu at the upper left, select Settings, and go to the
>   bottom, there's an "Allow Rotation" of the home screen option.  With
>   that enabled, the home screen will then be able to rotate to landscape
>   orientation when needed.  Daydream can then inherit that rotation and
>   display in landscape mode, too." -- May 18, 2016

Answer (score 0):

It's a shame that I didn't found any solution either, I had to use a nasty workaround which may or may not work for you, it is, setting the auto-rotation setting off, right before setting your layout:

In your DreamService class:

```
import android.provider.Settings;
<...>

    @Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {

    Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
            android.provider.Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 0);

    setContentView(R.layout.dream_main);
<...>
```

In your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```